# Double Integral over a triangular region (edge not rested on x or y axis)

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question:** solve $\iint \limits_{R}xydA $ over the triangular region: $(0,0), (2,1), (1,2)$

I'm thinking maybe I can first integrate along the y-axis; So find the equations of the segment $(0,0)$ to $(2,1)$: $y = \frac{1}{2} x$. Then the segment $(2,1)$ to $(1,2)$: $y=-x+3$. So: $$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{-x+3}(xy)dydx $$

I'm not sure if this is correct, the $dx$ integral could perhaps be from 0 to 1 instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting it into two integrals: 
$$\iint \limits_{R}xydA~~ = ~~\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=1} ~~\int\limits_{y=x/2}^{y=?}xy~dydx +  \int\limits_{x=1}^{x=2} ~~\int\limits_{y=x/2}^{y=?}xy~dydx$$
(fill in `?` with appropriate top boundary).
[image]